# Swift - SpriteKit : Make sprites reacting to eachothers if added with different "addchild" parents

Tags: ios, swift, sprite

I've added several sprite (SKSpriteNode) in my Scene like this:

```
let NPuzzle_Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "SKTexture.png")
NPuzzle0 = SKSpriteNode(texture: NPuzzle_Texture)
NPuzzle1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: NPuzzle_Texture)
NPuzzle2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: NPuzzle_Texture)
NPuzzle0.position = CGPoint (x: 100, y:125)
NPuzzle0.position = CGPoint (x: 300, y:125)
NPuzzle0.position = CGPoint (x: 500, y:125)
background.addChild(NPuzzle0)
background.addChild(NPuzzle1)
background.addChild(NPuzzle2)
```

I've also added several sprites in a different texture:

```
let Grey_Back = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Grey_Back.png")
grey_back = SKSpriteNode(texture: Grey_back)
grey_back.position = CGPoint (x: 1024, y:125)
grey_back.alpha = 0.5
background.addChild(grey_back)
```

Now I add new sprites (SKSpriteNode) to precedent grey_back like this:

```
grey_back.addChild(new_sprite1)
grey_back.addChild(new_sprite2)
grey_back.addChild(new_sprite3)
```

When I try to see if positions of new_sprite intersects with NPuzzle sprites, nothing is happening. But if the new_sprite are added to the scene with:

```
background.addChild(new_sprite0)
background.addChild(new_sprite1)
background.addChild(new_sprite2)
```

it works. In fact it doesn't work if the sprites have been added with differents parents (background and grey_back). What I don't understand is grey_back is the child of background, so, it should work. Why it doesn't ?

Here is an example of the code to check if sprites intersects eachothers:

```
switch selectedNode.name {

case "new_sprite0":
if selectedNode.frame.intersects(NPuzzle0.frame) && (selectedNode.angle == 0) {
```

Thanks !

Comment: frame is the frame relative to the parent node.  If you want to compare frames they must all be children of the same node.  Or else, you would have to translate the frames...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch selectedNode.name {
let framePoint = CGPointMake(selectedNode.frame.origin.x, selectedNode.frame.origin.y)
let translatedPoint = selectedNode.parent!.convertPoint(framePoint, toNode:NPuzzle0.parent!)
let translatedFrame = CGRectMake(translatedPoint.x, translatedPoint.y, selectedNode.frame.size.width, selectedNode.frame.size.height)
if translatedFrame.intersects(NPuzzle0.frame) && (selectedNode.zRotation == 0) 
{
    print("ok")
}
```

Obviously, because frames are relative to parents, the node MUST be added to the scene.  You can see I also used a forced unwrap for parent...

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I've tried the code you have noted but this makes no change. The intersects test still doesn't work. I would like to put puzzle parts on a large moving slider from left to right (4096 pixels width) and be able to pick up them to the scene. This is why I need a different parent (the slider wich has an alpha and moves from left to right wich is called grey_back) and the scene (background).

Comment: I've made several tries with your code and I finished to get better results (I think the conversion works) BUT I still get a fatal error when the frames intersect: "unexpected found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your code is working fine. In fact,I was deleteting SelectedNode later after the check, wich was creating this nil issue but it's now solved.